# Where is smart tag button in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have installed visual studio 2015 enterprise on windows 10. And I created a windows form application in c#. So normally, on visual studio 2013 I saw the a small triangle button like this:

[image: vs2013]

But on visual studio 2015, this button disappear. Is it removed? How can I re-enable it? Please help me! Sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Smart Tags are supported in Visual Studio 2015.
I have VS2015 Enterprise Update 1 runned in Windows 10. That triangle button is visible by default at the same location as in VS2013. Try `Shift+Alt+F10`, it is default key combination to show Smart Tags.

Also, check `Tools -> Options -> Windows Forms Designer -> Automatically Open Smart Tags` property value.